# what is 1E28 in oracle sequence max value?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, sequence

Recently I used select * from user_sequence to display all the sequence in my database server. I found out that most of the max value column is 1E28 or 1E27. What does this means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those numbers are in *exponential notation*.

```
1E27 = 1000000000000000000000000000  
1E28 = 10000000000000000000000000000
```

The part after the `E` indicates how many following zeros there are.